# how to define a constructor for implicit type conversion in argument?

Tags: c++

Recently I was using functions in `<filesystem>`, e.g. `std::filesystem::exists`. These functions accept `std::filesystem::path`. I noticed passing `const char*` like `"/abc"` to function like `std::filesystem::exists` works, e.g. `std::filesystem::exists("/abc")`

My question is, it seems like when passing `const char*` to `std::filesystem::exists`, we are doing some implicit conversion from `const char*` to `filesystem::path`.

1. Which constructor handles this on `filesystem::path` class?
2. How can I write a constructor for this type of conversion? Below code doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure what's wrong. (*I'm a bit new to C++*).

```
class A {
  A(const char*& msg) {
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
  }
};

void func(const A& p) {
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  func("123"); // No matching function for call to 'func'
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make the constructor Public.

And secondly constructor for `A` in your code is taking `const char*&` which is reference to `const char*`, so `const char*` won't be implicitically converted to `A` because `const char*&` is lvalue reference and `const char*` is rvalue (basically nameless temporary)

Try this it will work

```
#include<iostream>
class A {
public:
  A(const char* msg) {
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
  }
};

void func(const A& p) {
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  func("123"); // No matching function for call to 'func'
  return 0;
}
```

> Which constructor handles this on filesystem::path class

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/path), (5) constructor

`template< class Source >
path( const Source& source, format fmt = auto_format );`

takes care of implicit type conversions from `const char*` to `std::filesystem::path`

Comment: Do answer the first part as well.

Comment: Ohh, nice. Why doesn't `const char*&` work? Is there a term for this kind of constructor that I can search for, e.g. is it a copy constructor?

Comment: @Daiwei it is a parameterised constructor.

Comment: The end of your answer is incorrect. `string_type` is `std::string` or `std::wstring`, so you need a conversion from `const char [4]` (`"abc"`) to `string_type` and then to `path` for `exists`, which are two user-defined conversions, and the standard only allow one user-defined conversion in an implicit conversion sequence. The constructor used is the 5th one in the link you posted: `template< class Source > path( const Source& source, format fmt = auto_format );`

Comment: @Holt thanks for pointing it out, yeah my mistake, updated the answer